# Need a global NSTimer variable, or something similar

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, i need to start a timer in the app delegate method applicationDidEnterBackground:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
     globalBackgroundTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:30 invocation:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

the timer is declared like so in app delegate.h:

```
extern  NSTimer * globalBackgroundTimer;
```

While the timer runs, i receive background location updates (is enabled in plist), in a view controller, and i want to check constantly in locationManager:didUpdateLocations: 
For when the timer has expired so i can end the location updates.

```
... //code omitted
//this is called repeatedly when the app is in the background, and checks whether the global variable is instantiated, and if it has expired.
if(globalBackgroundTimer)
{
    NSLog(@"timer alive");
    if(!globalBackgroundTimer.isValid)
    {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        NSLog(@"background timer invalid, stopping location updates");
    }
}
```

But i can't make it work (Mach-O-linker error),
however i also read that this approach was ill-advised. So what do you guys suggest?

Comment: Did you add `NSTimer * globalBackgroundTimer;` to one .m file (outside of any class) such as your app delegate .m file?

Comment: That actually made the variable work, thanks! Next problem is that the timer doesn't invalidate itself for some reason. From what i can read, it is supposed to invalidate itself if repeat = NO. but the code never gets into the if(!globalBackgroundTImer.isValid)

Edit--- 
Changing it to a scheduled timer made it work. :)

Could you explain why i should add the NSTimer *globalBackgroundTimer to a .m file?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out a mechanism to store the state of the timer when the app enters the background (NSUserDefaults or Documents sandbox).  Then, when the app enters foreground, recalculate the difference using the NSDate information you saved.

(I realize this may already have been what you were doing before you posted this question.)